# Original Source File Row Count when having both a Happy Green and a Red Redirect path

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a Data Flow task that directs rows into a database table (the happy green path) and redirects rows to an error file.

What I would like to do is add a column to both data flows which represents the record count of the original source file, not the count of the number of records that flowed to either direction. I'm thinking that I need an input/outout *variable* to a two Script Tasks. If a row if directed to either path, the global variable is incremented and its value mapped to an Output Column.

Does this seem like a correct approach? I've never locked variables (or used them much) and I am wondering if the locking in the Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row) method of the script task is the right or even correct place to do it. Any advise on how to do this or examples would be appreciated.

Again, I have seen exampels on how to count rows to a Script component, but they involve a Scripting Task module level variable rather than an external variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You would think the Script Task would work but it won't. The problem is that the way SSIS Variables work is that you can only update them in the OnPostExecute Event. That's why you see the examples modifying a scripting task variable in the ProcessInputRow events and only in the wrap up phase are they even *allowed* to try modify the Variable.

So you have Script Task 1 and Script Task 2 both trying to modify the same global value but because of locking and synchronization junk, it's not going to work.

I think your best approach would be use two Row Count Transformations. Have one count the Happy rows and one count the Angry rows. If you need a combined answer, simply add a third variable, RowsTotalInput and let it be an Expression of `@[User::RowsInputHappy] + @[User::RowsInputAngry]`

Comment: What I really need isn't a total count of the rows. if the two flows are inserted into two tables, I want to be able to identify the row number in the original source file from which the record came ragrdless of which path it took. But you didn't confirm my suspicion that it wouldn't be straight fwd using a variable that was incremented by two tasks.